# Find two column in laravel which have equal values via Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I am working on a project where I have a table market which has a buyer_id column and a seller_id column. When a seller puts something on the market, the seller_id and buyer_id are the same which means that the product is for sale right now. After the sale, the buyer_id changes to whoever bought the product.

Now the place in my application where I am showing all the products up for sale I am doing this query via Eloquent:

```
$market_records = Market::where('seller_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->where('seller_id', '=', 'buyer_id')->get();
```

I want only the products up for sale which are not by the same user who has logged in and I want to have only those products where the seller_id and buyer_id is same. Now the problem in the second `where` statement is that the that it is comparing the seller_id to the string `'buyer_id'` which is not what I want. What is way with which I can only fetch the records where the buyer_id is equal to the `seller_id`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to use `whereRaw` to do it:

```
$market_records = Market::where('seller_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
                         ->whereRaw('seller_id = buyer_id')->get();
```

Anyone looking for this solution keep in mind since Laravel 5.2 it's possible to use `whereColumn` method instead, so above code in **Laravel 5.2 and up** could look like this:

```
$market_records = Market::where('seller_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
                         ->whereColumn('seller_id', 'buyer_id')->get();
```

You can find details in [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13549)

Comment: and how do u do if you want the columns to not be equal?

Comment: @LachezarRaychev use `->whereColumn('seller_id', '<>','buyer_id')`

Answer (score 22):

In recent Laravel versions you can use `whereColumn` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)):

```
$same = Market::whereColumn('seller_id', 'buyer_id')->get();
```